# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - FaveButton Swift 4.2 Upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I upgraded the project from Swif 4 to 4.2 and got the issue below issue. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: how do you add this in your project via  Carthage or CocoaPod or package or manual

Comment: Added via cocoaPod

Comment: There are solution generally works is, first remove library prod and then install it again. I have faced same issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I an see in the `.swift-version` file over at https://github.com/xhamr/fave-button it is still using Swift 4.0 and therefore you need to compile it using the correct Swift version.

To mix this with your project using Swift 4.2, open the `xcworkspace`, and in the `Pods.xcodeproj` navigate to the build settings for `Fave-Button` (or similar) and search for the `SWIFT_VERSION`. Set it to `4.0` and it should compile correctly.

(I did not try this on my own, but this should be general behaviour and not an issue of `Fave-Button`)